# Export an object of class ggmap in R

Tags: r, export, ggmap

I need to use a map that I load from ggmap in a lab where there's no internet. I was wondering if there's an read.table function for those type of object.

This is the code I'have try:

```
mtl <- get_map(location = c(lon = -73.705951 , lat = 45.541598), zoom = 11
                , maptype = "terrain",
                source = "google", color = "color")

save(mtl, file="mtlmap.RData")
test <- load("mtlmap.RData")

ggmap(test)
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: ggmap plots objects of class ggmap, see ?get_map
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did the solution I provided work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could simply use `save` and `load`?

```
myggmap <- get_googlemap(...) #add your params here

save(myggmap, file="tmp1.RData")
rm(myggmap)
load("tmp1.Rdata")
ggmap(myggmap)
```

Or a bit fancier:

```
if(file.exists("tmp1.RData")&file.info("tmp1.RData")$size>0)
load("tmp1.Rdata")
```

Comment: I have update my post so you could see the code and the error.

Comment: `load` loads the saved object into the environment, you don't have to assign it to anything